# Why doesn't auto return type deduction work with constexpr in Visual C++ 2015 update 3?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, constexpr, auto

This code compiles and runs well in both GCC 4.9+ and Clang 3.5+(with flag -std=c++14), but gives a compilation error in VC++2015. Notice the auto return type in the `operator*`:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A {
    int i;
    constexpr A() : i(0) {};
    constexpr A(int i) : i(i) {};
    constexpr auto operator* (const A &a) const
    {
        return A(i * a.i);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    constexpr auto b = A(100) * A(200);
    printf("%d", b.i);
    return 0;
}
```

> main.cpp(67): error C2127: 'b': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression

But if I replace the `auto` with `A`, it compiles well:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A {
    int i;
    constexpr A() : i(0) {};
    constexpr A(int i) : i(i) {};
    constexpr A operator* (const A &a) const
    {
        return A(i * a.i);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    constexpr auto b = A(100) * A(200);
    printf("%d", b.i);
    return 0;
}
```

> output: 20000

What gives?

Comment: Incomplete C++14 support? Not sure what you want us to say really.

Comment: Obviously MSVC bug. Operator overloads are just normal functions in the end.

Comment: This bug is still present in today's daily build (compiler v19.10.24603.0); please [file a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) and post a link to it here so we may upvote it.

Comment: @ildjarn I logged in and clicked on "Report a bug", and it says "You are not authorized to submit the feedback for this connection.", no bug report forms in sight...

Comment: @MujjinGun : Odd... [I've filed it for you](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3105455), please upvote and mark as reproducible if you can.

Comment: Have you considered trying their c2 compiler?  It uses clang on the front end...